# Eloquent Foreign Key to Same Table

Tags: schema, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel 4's Eloquent,

i have a table `user` and a field `user.friend_id` which is an also an id of a user..

but when i try to create a new user with friend_id = 0, the foreign key fails..

and when friend_id = 1, it succeeds.

I have this in my user's schema builder

```
$table->unsignedInteger('friend_id')->default(0)->nullable();
```

what should I be doing here?

should i have just created a pivot table instead?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can have more than one friend, then yes, you should have a pivot table

**User table**

```
id | name
1  |  Laurence
2  |  Ben
3  |  Jane
```

**Users_Friend table**

```
   user_id | friend_id
    1      |  2
    1      |  3
```

This means Laurence is friends with Ben and Jane

Comment: but it is like tree.. imagine a pyramid of networking people.. one user can have many friends.. and that friend can have more 'downlines'

Answer (score 5):

You should not set  default value 0 for a null able foreign key.

**Correct way:**

```
$table->unsignedInteger('friend_id')->nullable();
```

**Explanation:**

```
$table->unsignedInteger('friend_id')->default(0)->nullable();
```

When you try to insert a new record, and leave the friend_id blank.

- The database takes the default value for the field ie: 0
- since it's a foreign  key, to maintain relational integrity, it will look for a record having primary key 0. (which naturally does not exist)

Comment: Also make sure that your id has compatible type for your RDBMS foreign keys (e.g. INTEGER). Otherwise you will receive something like "errno: 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed".